# Can't understand the last step

Tags: statistics

I'm confused about how they concluded  that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} b/n = b$ (second link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B307Z.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds1Ma.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a **constant** $b$ to itself $n$ times and dividing the result by $n$ equals $b$. Thus the sample mean over $n$ $b's$ is $b$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing my confusion